# Split Object to array of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to separate the object below into two objects following the year in the keys.
Backend response is a.

```
const a = {
  "id": "2",
  "2019_progrSin": "2",
  "2019_percResponsabilita": "30",
  "2019_flag": "B",
  "2019_tipoResponsabilitaSinistro": "O",
  "2019_anno": "2019",
  "2019_codComp": "O",
  "2018_progrSin": "2",
  "2018_percResponsabilita": "50",
  "2018_flag": "Y",
  "2018_tipoResponsabilitaSinistro": "I",
  "2018_anno": "2018",
  "2018_codComp": "O"
}
```

To display a in my table I want obtain b from a, like:

```
const b = [
 {
   "2019_progrSin": "2",
   "2019_percResponsabilita": "30",
   "2019_flag": "B",
   "2019_tipoResponsabilitaSinistro": "O",
   "2019_anno": "2019",
   "2019_codComp": "O",
 },
 {
   "2018_progrSin": "2",
   "2018_percResponsabilita": "50",
   "2018_flag": "Y",
   "2018_tipoResponsabilitaSinistro": "I",
   "2018_anno": "2018",
   "2018_codComp": "O"
 }
]
```

The property can be more. ( like "2017_flag" / "2016_flag" and so on)

Comment: Can you show the code that you have wrote in order to achieve the solution? Where are you stuck at? What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: Why is this tagged React when there is no React code in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). This would also work:

```js
const input = {
  id: "2",
  "2019_progrSin": "2",
  "2019_percResponsabilita": "30",
  "2019_flag": "B",
  "2019_tipoResponsabilitaSinistro": "O",
  "2019_anno": "2019",
  "2019_codComp": "O",
  "2018_progrSin": "2",
  "2018_percResponsabilita": "50",
  "2018_flag": "Y",
  "2018_tipoResponsabilitaSinistro": "I",
  "2018_anno": "2018",
  "2018_codComp": "O",
};

const output = Object.values(
  Object.entries(input).reduce((prev, [key, value]) => {
    const [year] = key.split("_");
    if (!isNaN(year)) {
      if (!prev[year]) {
        prev[year] = {};
      }
      prev[year][key] = value;
    }
    return prev;
  }, {})
);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this parsing all the item like this :

```
const yearObj = {}
let results = []

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  if(key != "id") {
    const year = key.split('_')[0]
    if(!yearObj[year]) yearObj[year] = {}

      yearObj[year][key] = value
   }
}

for (const value of Object.values(yearObj)) {
    results.push(value)
}
```

This could be even more specific using a regex to parse keys of the object to get only 4 digit numbers